# Is it compulsory for app to support all iPad devices

Tags: ios, iphone

I developed it only for iPhone but Apple has this rule that iPhone app must support iPad. Therefore, I developed another version that also includes iPad support and design. Is it necessary for app to support all iPad devices.i.e. iPad 2, iPad Air etc? Or only support to one iPad device will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't compulsory, you can set your app only for iPhone devices and you can install it in iPad too. The only thing is that the appearance of your app in iPad devices going to be similar than in iPhone devices.

Comment: Now, I included added universal support because the auto layout option was not working for iPhone app. I mean, for universal app how many device can be supported?